# Typesetting pH values

Tags: siunitx, chemistry

I'm using the `siunitx`  package to typeset units. I don't believe that there is an option for pH values. I could define a new unit using e.g. `\DeclareSIUnit{\pH}{pH}`, but that would make the value come out the wrong way round(`5 pH`  rather than `pH 5`). Is there a way to fix this?

Another idea would be to simply use `$5$ pH`, but I'm sure there's a better solution, maybe in a chemistry package. Many thanks!

Comment: `chemmacros` offers the `\pH` command.

Comment: pH is not a unit ...

Comment: I never claimed it was one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pH is a unitless value, so in `siunitx` terms the value is simple `\num{5}` or similar. One could create a `\pH` command, or as pointed out in comments load `chemmacros` to provide one. That might lead to

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suinitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ProvideDocumentCommand\pH{\textrm{pH}}
\begin{document}
\pH~\num{5}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, I tested your code. It has some errors. May yo help me adjust it?